# How to sum each row column values to subsequent row column values and create new dataframe with new and old rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have big data frame with different product ids,corresponding prod_descriptions and quantities.There are product ids having sub products(prod_desc2,prod_desc3...etc) either doesn't have product id or not maped to main prod id(1111,333) and its values are empty in prod_id column as shown in sample DF.

```
Sample DF
prod_id prod_description    col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
1111    prod_desc1          10      20      30      45      25  
        prod_desc2          15      17      16      28      nan
        prod_desc3          15      17      5       nan     nan
2222    prod_desc1          5       10      15      7       10
2223    prod_desc1          15      10      25      10      10
333     prod_desc1          10      15      20      23      25  
        prod_desc2          25      5       25      10      nan
```

I would like to roll up the quantities of  prod_desc2 & prod_desc3 to prod_desc1 level and create a new DF along with other prod _id's(2222,2223)shown in desired output.So that each product id will have one row cummulative sum of its sub products.

```
Desired Output 
prod_id prod_description    col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
1111    prod_desc1          40      54      51      73      25  
2222    prod_desc1          5       10      15      7       10
2223    prod_desc1          15      10      25      10      10
333     prod_desc1          35      20      45      33      25
```

Below is the "partial" code which i tried and having trouble in summing of column values of prod id row and no_prod_id columns and saving them in new dataframe along with other prod_ids.Please do the needfull.

```
Empty rows were filled with no_prod_id 

prod_id     prod_description    col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
1111        prod_desc1          10      20      30      45      25  
no_prod_id  prod_desc2          15      17      16      28      nan
no_prod_id  prod_desc3          15      17      5       nan     nan
2222        prod_desc1          5       10      15      7       10
2223        prod_desc1          15      10      25      10      10
333         prod_desc1          10      15      20      23      25  
no_prod_id  prod_desc2          25      5       25      10      nan

null_value_count=[]
rolled_up_values=[]
for i in df.index:
    if df.iloc[i,0]=="no_prod_id": #pick no_prod_id row
        x=df.iloc[i,:]  #save null value row
        if x.isnull().sum().sum()==df.shape[1]: # check if no_prod_id is having all nulls 
            null_value_cunt.append(i)         #save index for later deleting it from DF
        else:
            if df.iloc[i-1,0]!= "no_prod_id": #check previus row has main prod id 
                y=df.iloc[i-1,:] # save main prod id row
                for val in  range(1,len(y)):    #get each value of main prod id 
                    rolled_up_values.append(x[val]+y[val]) #sum with no_prod_id value save the out in 
                                                           #list for updating in a new DF
```

Answer (score 1):

first `ffill`

```
df['prod_id'] = df['prod_id'].ffill()
print(df)
    prod_id prod_description  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0   1111.0       prod_desc1    10    20    30  45.0  25.0
1   1111.0       prod_desc2    15    17    16  28.0   NaN
2   1111.0       prod_desc3    15    17     5   NaN   NaN
3   2222.0       prod_desc1     5    10    15   7.0  10.0
4   2223.0       prod_desc1    15    10    25  10.0  10.0
5    333.0       prod_desc1    10    15    20  23.0  25.0
6    333.0       prod_desc2    25     5    25  10.0   NaN
```

---

then we drop your prod_description and groupby the remainng columns,

```
df_new = df.drop('prod_description',axis=1).groupby('prod_id').sum().reset_index()

df_new.insert(1,'prod_description','prod_desc1') # reinsert columns.
```

---

result, note i've just added in a custom sort to match ur output.

```
idx = df_new['prod_id'].astype(str).str[1].astype(int).sort_values().index
print(df_new.loc[idx])
   prod_id prod_description  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
1   1111.0       prod_desc1    40    54    51  73.0  25.0
2   2222.0       prod_desc1     5    10    15   7.0  10.0
3   2223.0       prod_desc1    15    10    25  10.0  10.0
0    333.0       prod_desc1    35    20    45  33.0  25.0
```

or as anky_91 kindly pointed out, we can reduce the lines of code to a simple two-liner by using `.assign` and `sort=False`

```
df['prod_id'] = df['prod_id'].ffill()
df.groupby("prod_id", sort=False, as_index=False).sum().assign(
prod_description="prod_desc1"
).reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
```

---

result

```
   prod_id prod_description  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0   1111.0       prod_desc1    40    54    51  73.0  25.0
1   2222.0       prod_desc1     5    10    15   7.0  10.0
2   2223.0       prod_desc1    15    10    25  10.0  10.0
3    333.0       prod_desc1    35    20    45  33.0  25.0
```

Comment: Nice solution, however you dont need to sort index again, the order can be maintained by passing `sort=False` under groupby :) eg: `df.groupby('prod_id',sort=False,as_index=False).sum().assign(prod_description='prod_desc1').reindex(df.columns,axis=1)`

Comment: @Datanovice,concise soultion.can you explain `str[1].astype(int)` in custom sort?

Comment: @anky_91 oh, awesome totally forgot about that! i should refer to the docs more, do you want to add it as an answer or can I edit mine ? (:

Comment: @Optimizer it's basically just taking the first digit of your number i.e `1234` is `1` it's just to keep your original sort and may not work with your actual data. Try Anky_91 solution imo.

Comment: @Datanovice feel free to add it to your answer :)